# 'Could not find schema..' messages when nlog.config file is created

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, nlog

When I create a nlog.config file in the root of my project , I get the following messages

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:nlog'.  
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:targets'.       
This is an invalid xsi:type 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:File'.    
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:target'.    
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'.     
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'fileName'. 
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:rules'. 
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:logger'.    
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'minlevel'.     
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'writeTo'.
```

The code that I used was

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    
      <!-- the targets to write to -->
      <targets>
        <!-- write logs to file  -->
        <target name="allfile" xsi:type="File"
                fileName="c:\CsharpTutorials\EmployeeManagement\DemoLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"/>
      </targets>
    
      <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
      <rules>
        <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
      </rules>
    </nlog>
```

I am following a tutorial and this was the code that was used. How can I rectify the problem?

Comment: What is the code supposed to accomplish? Help us help you. Tell us everything. You're more likely to get assistance from the community if you show that you've tried to resolve the issue on your own and researched the problem, but come up short.

Comment: Sorry about it. 
The code is supposed to tell  NLog , a third party logging provider, to write the log information to the nlog file in the DemoLogs folder. So it creates the file(nlog) and the folder(DemoLogs) and  logs  the errors in a text file. 
It is logging the errors/exceptions properly , but these messages are sitting in the error list box. 
I have just started learning .net and do not fully understand it.I have browsed around but couldn't find anything to fix it. I was hoping to get some pointers which might help me to properly search for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll have to ignore comments like elersong's and keep learning. This is part of the learning and research process.

If you're asking about the schema errors,

> Could not find schema information for the element

this worked for me

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">
    ...
</nlog>
```